# How can I draw a single triangle from a Vertex Buffer Object and set its color?

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl, opengl-es, vbo

I have created a Vertex Buffer Object containing only vertices for triangles, for drawing with the GL_TRIANGLES option. My VBO has no color information because I change the color every frame.

Now I'm trying to draw individual triangles in a loop after setting the default vertex color like this in every iteration:

```
glColor4f(red, green, blue, 1);
```

But I'm not sure how to perform the actual drawing.

Must I use `glDrawArrays` if I want to pick one or two triangles out of the VBO to draw them with a specific color, or must I use `glDrawElements`?

Is there a more efficient way to set the color for each triangle in the VBO and then draw it? Or is it fine to call `glColor44` and `glDrawArrays` in a loop for every frame?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I would rather suggest to ignore the slightly higher memory cost and just store a color with each vertex inside the VBO and therefore just duplicate the triangle's color for each of the triangle's vertices (you cannot set per-triangle colors). This will most probably be much more efficient than drawing single triangles in a loop. Keep in mind that the advantage of VBOs is not only their possible GPU storage, but also the fact that you don't need driver calls for each and every triangle or even vertex. So just duplicate your per-triangle colors into per-vertex colors and draw everything with a single call to `glDrawArrays` (`glDrawElements` won't buy you much if you need to duplicate almost every vertex anyway, which makes indices just useless).

Said that, you can of course draw individual triangles with `glDrawArrays`, that's what the `first` and `count` parameters are for. So if you have a VBO containing the 9 vertices of 3 triangles, just call

```
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 3, 3);
```

to draw only the 2nd triangle. That easy. And likewise can you use the `count` and `offset` parameters of `glDrawElements` to select a particular part of the index array to draw.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot! So basically I would just go ahead and create an array of structs with interleaved vertex-color-vertex-color-(...) data, and then glMapBufferOES + memcpy colors over to the GPU in every frame. How much of a pain is it to call memcpy in a loop for each color, every frame? Is that a trade-off with interleaved data? Otherwise, if not interleaved, I could call memcpy just once with a big chunk of colors every frame. What do you think is better?

Comment: @openfrog Hard to answer, since interleaving may be better. But then you are right that updating a whole chunk of memory instead of many scattered ones might also be better. In this case you could even put the positions in one VBO and the colors in another, so you can update the whole color VBO, which again has some performance advantages (if done right) over updating a part. It needs to be tested, I guess.

Comment: Using two VBOs makes sense. Does this require the use of indices?

Comment: @openfrog No, why should it? Just bind the correct VBO (using `glBindBuffer`) before calling `gl...Pointer`. Indices are for indexed drawing. If you don't want/need indices, don't use indices.